# Getting instance involved in OWL Restriction classes through SPARQL 1.1

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl

I'm creating two classes `Book` and `Person`, and an object property `hasAuthor`:

- `Person` has subClasses `Man` and `Women`.
- `Book` has subClasses `Hard_bounded_book` and `Soft_bounded_book`.

I'm creating another subClass of `Book` as `Book_With_Atleast_One_Male_Author` using an OWL restriction as follows:

```
:Book_With_Atleast_One_Male_Author rdfs:subClassOf [
  rdf:type owl:Class ;
  owl:intersectionOf (
                      :Book 
                      [ a owl:Restriction ;
                        owl:onProperty bf:hasAuthor ;
                        owl:someValuesFrom :Male ]
                      )
] .
```

Now I create some instances of `Book` and `Person` and relationships:

```
:Hard_bounded_book1 rdf:type :Hard_bounded_book .
:Hard_bounded_book2 rdf:type :Hard_bounded_book .
:Soft_bounded_book1 rdf:type :Soft_bounded_book .
:Soft_bounded_book2 rdf:type :Soft_bounded_book .
:Male1 rdf:type :Male .
:Male2 rdf:type :Male .
:Female1 rdf:type :Female .
:Female2 rdf:type :Female .
:Hard_bounded_book1 :hasAuthor :Male1
:Hard_bounded_book1 :hasAuthor :Male2
:Hard_bounded_book1 :hasAuthor :Female1
:Hard_bounded_book1 :hasAuthor :Female2
:Soft_bounded_book1 :hasAuthor :Male1
:Soft_bounded_book2 :hasAuthor :Female1
```

When I write a SPARQL query to get the instances of class `Book_With_Atleast_One_Male_Author`, I don't get anything. 
Please let me know if you have any idea of what is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Which API do you use to use inference with SPARQL?

Comment: I am loading it in GraphDB  software with OQL2-QL ruleset.

Comment: I hope you meant `OWL2-QL`. As the answer below correctly states, you have to use an equivalence axiom instead of a simple subsumption which infers only in one direction.

Comment: Yes, I meant OWL2-QL. I tried what Median suggested, but it did not work. Turtle File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4oeZMBx078zWmF3R181M1hCSkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you will not get! You are defining `:Book_With_Atleast_One_Male_Author` as a `subClassOf` of that intersection between `Book` and the `restriction`.

The `subClassOf` semantics:

```
Sub subClassOf Super
```

means that each instance of `Sub` is an instance of `Super`.

That means that instances of `:Book_With_Atleast_One_Male_Author` must follow this `restriction` you defined, but that doesn't mean that arbitrary individuals following this restriction are instances of `Book_With_Atleast_One_Male_Author`.

What you can do is that you define `:Book_With_Atleast_One_Male_Author` as an equivalent class of the intersection between `Book` and an anonymous class for that `restriction` you created. As a consequence, each individual that is both `Book` and meets the `restriction`, will be (with a reasoner running) classified as a `:Book_With_Atleast_One_Male_Author`.

Here is how you can do it:

```
:Book_With_Atleast_One_Male_Author rdf:type owl:Class ;
                               owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf (  :Book :EquivalentToBookAndHasMaleAuthor ) ;rdf:type owl:Class ] .

:EquivalentToBookAndHasMaleAuthor rdf:type owl:Class ;
                              owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction; owl:onProperty  :hasAuthor ; owl:someValuesFrom :Male] .
```

Comment: I just loaded in graphDB software with OWL2-QL ruleset, but it did not work. I have a file, but I dont know how can share the file with you.

Comment: What did you load into GraphDB? What is that file? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @Sidd You have to change you ontology like MedianHilal suggested und load that into your GraphDB dataset as well

Comment: @MedianHilal Don't forget that there are restrictions on the OWL2-QL profile: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_QL  For instance, the `owl:someValuesFrom` in a subclass can only be used with `owl:Thing` as filler.

Comment: @Median I meant the turtle file that contains all the classes (Book, Person,...), relationships/objectProperty (hasAuthor), and instances (Male1,.....)

Comment: Please see the attached file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4oeZMBx078zWmF3R181M1hCSkk

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, that OWL axiom is beyond `OWL2-QL`, thus, will not work

Comment: As @AKSW says, this is beyond OWL2-QL. You still can, however, recreate the repository and assign the rule set parameter on creation to OWL2-RL, that should work. Alternatively, you can modify the current rule set used using: INSERT DATA {
    _:b sys:addRuleset "owl2-rl"
}

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_RL and http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/reasoning.html